# "Possibly undefined value", how to make null safe?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Looking for some help with Facebook's Flow.

I have the following code:

```
function getValues(obj? : Object) {

    if (obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
            return obj[key];
        });
    }

    return [];
}
```

I get the following error with flow version `0.37.0`:

```
65:             return obj[key];
                       ^^^^^^^^ access of computed property/element. Computed property/element cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
65:             return obj[key];
                       ^^^ undefined
```

Am I making a mistake here, or should this code be null safe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an answer, but there is [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: Also I think this is a flow bug. You can submit an issue. A redundant check will fix it: https://tryflow.org/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZ2V0VmFsdWVzKG9iaj8gOiBPYmplY3QpIHsKCiAgICBpZiAob2JqKSB7CiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIE9iamVjdC5rZXlzKG9iaikubWFwKGtleSA9PiB7CiAgICAgICAgICAgIGlmIChvYmopIHsKICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiBvYmpba2V5XTsKICAgICAgICAgICAgfQogICAgICAgIH0pOwogICAgfQoKICAgIHJldHVybiBbXTsKfQo=

Comment: Object.values unfortunately doesn't have the browser support :( Also this is just example code, I see the same issue for other custom functions

Comment: Yeah went with the redundant check for now, still hoping to know if there's anything I'm missing. I added a github issue too.

Comment: I believe flow just isn't smart enough to know that the `if` should also limit the possible options for `obj` inside nested functions like the `map` callback.

Comment: System.out(I mean output it somewhere) the "obj[key]" value to check where it fails. What is in that value at the moment of failure. You should handle the error accordingly.

Comment: @MarcoSchoolenberg it's a compile time error with flow, not a run-time error.

Comment: Javascript is interpreted as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Flow is pessimistic about refinements, it considers that every function call could modify `obj`. As for a fix, you can use a `const` [binding](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#caveats)

```
function getValues(obj?: Object) {
  const o = obj
  return o ?
    Object.keys(o).map(key => o[key]) :
    []
}
```

Comment: In ES2017 you can do the same behavior with `Object.values(object)`